# Android. Create own Jar Library

Tags: android, sdk

I created own library in android studio according https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html
But when I went through all steps I got `AAR` file (not `JAR`).

1. How to create Jar library?
2. Can Jar library contain manifest file with `receivers`, `cervices` etc?

Comment: 1. by using "java" plugin instead "com.android.application" 2. no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to create Jar library?

Create a suitable Gradle task. This snippet defines one task per build variant:

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    def name = variant.buildType.name
    def task = project.tasks.create "jar${name.capitalize()}", Jar
    task.dependsOn variant.javaCompile
    task.from variant.javaCompile.destinationDir
    task.baseName = "..."
    task.version = "..."
}
```

(where you would need to fill in the `baseName` and `version` values to go into the JAR filename)

> Can Jar library contain manifest file with receivers, cervices etc?

No. That is what an AAR is for. For Android app development, you generally use AARs, distributed by artifact repositories, so that you can have manifests/resources/assets in addition to Java code.